# Obtaining a memoryview object from a ctypes.c_void_p object

Tags: python

I have a void pointer to a block of pixels (retrieved from `SDL_LockTexture` call). I need to give this block to PyCairo. Specifically, `cairo.ImageSurface.create_for_data`. This function accepts `memoryview` object, but I have a `ctypes.c_void_p` object for the pixels.

Is it possible to create a `memoryview` given by a `c_void_p` along with a length in bytes? Any large copying is not really acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

The `memoryview` implementation in CPython was completely rewritten in Python 3.3, so this answer only applies to Python 3.3 and later. It's current as of Python 3.10.

```
from ctypes import pythonapi, c_char_p, c_ssize_t, c_int, py_object
pythonapi.PyMemoryView_FromMemory.argtypes = (c_char_p, c_ssize_t, c_int)
pythonapi.PyMemoryView_FromMemory.restype = py_object
```

This imports `pythonapi.PyMemoryView_FromMemory` and sets its prototype, so you can use it more safely. This API *does* let you insert use-after-free bugs in your Python code, though, so be careful! [According to the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memoryview.html), the function's C prototype is:

```c
PyObject *PyMemoryView_FromMemory(char *mem, Py_ssize_t size, int flags)
```

That last parameter can either be `0x200` (read/write) or `0x100` (read-only). You'll want `0x200` for your use-case:

```
view = pythonapi.PyMemoryView_FromMemory(pointer, length, 0x200)
```